# Is it possible the restart a docker container which it's network deleted?

Tags: docker, containers, devops, docker-network

I tried to remove a costume network that is connected to a container. As you can imagine I didn't, because of the container. I stopped it and then removed the network. When I tried to restart the container, I didn't because the container is not connected to any network. Then tried to connect to different networks but I can't. So, is there any way to restart that container again?

Comment: have you tried adding the network again?

Comment: @Turing85 I did but not worked.

Comment: How do you start the container? Are you using docker-compose?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SergioSantiago Just docker, No compose or swarm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After deleting the network the id of the deleted network is given in the output.
We can recreate the same network using that id:

```
docker network create "deleted_network_id"
```

after the recreation connect that network to the container:

```
docker network connect "network_id" "container"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
docker run -itd --network=networkName containerName
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/

Comment: "run" only works for images, mine is a stopped container:(

Comment: Deleting the stopped container and creating a new one is pretty routine, particularly if you need to change Docker-level settings like this.

Comment: @DavidMaze That's not that important, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

1. Recreate the network with the same name and get it's id.
2. Edit container's `config.v2.json`, update the `NetworkID` with the new id in `NetworkSettings.Networks`
3. Restart docker service and restart the container